# Problem connecting remotely to SQL Server after migrating to other server

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with my SQL Server database. I have two servers and my database first was on one of them and I had a NodeJS program which is executing stored procedures in this database.

After I created a backup of my database and restored it on the new server, everything seems correct and I can run all the stored procedures in SQL Server, but my NodeJS program can only run the procedures which are in the `dbo` schema, and it can not run the procedures which are in user login.

I have created the user login in this server and I have mapped it to the login and schema of my database. What should I do?

Comment: So what happens when you do try to execute them? Do you get an error? What is the error..?

Comment: the NodeJS program shows "Failure when receiving data from the peer".I think it just shows timeout in getting answer

Answer (score 0):

It may be that either the user account which NodeJS is connecting to does not have permission to the schema which you would need to explicitly grant or it may be that the user does not have execute permission on that schema.

You can use T-SQL something like the following to create an appropriate role and give your user permission to it;

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::schema_name TO db_executor
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_executor', 'Username'
```

For more information on the syntax and detail, take a look here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15